# Error while installing scikit-learn 19.1 with python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to install scikit-learn 19.1 due to some project requirements and it's producing the following error:

```
1 warning and 15 errors generated.
error: Command "g++ -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.o.d" failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Python 3.8 is not officially supported by NumPy or scikit-learn yet. We strongly suggest you stick with python 3.7 for now, until you see a 3.8 designation in the "Programming Language" section of the PyPI numpy page (probably several weeks) or until an Anaconda release with Python 3.8 is available (probably several months)

So it looks like it might be the underlying dependencies just not working with 3.8 yet. I actually had a similar issue with another package last week. You will probably have luck if you get a 3.7.5 install. Make sure you get the right platform (x86 for 32-bit, x64 for 64 bit) and make sure you check the box to add it to your path.

Comment: I am getting same error with python3.7. What can I do about that then ?